# When performing the "opposite" operation in a category, can you reverse arrows that are part of an object's definition?

Tags: category-theory, duality-theorems, slice-category

I'm reading Emily Riehl's *Category Theory in Context* and pondering Exercise 1.2.i, where the author writes "Defining $\mathcal{C}/c$ to be $(c/\mathcal{C}^{op})^{op}$," in an effort to exhibit duality between the slice and co-slice categories.  If you allow yourself complete freedom to just "reverse all the arrows" in the underlying commutative diagrams of the underlying category $\mathcal{C}$, this makes sense, but I get stuck when I try to step through the construction.

So, we start with $\mathcal{C}$, and we have objects $x,y,c$ and arrows $f:c\rightarrow x$, $g:c\rightarrow y$ and $h:x\rightarrow y$ such that $g=hf$.

Moving to $\mathcal{C}^{op}$, we have the same objects $x,y,c$, and now we have arrows that are the reverse of all the arrows in $\mathcal{C}$.  But, the construction of $c/\mathcal{C}^{op}$ still requires that we consider, in this categories, arrows $r^{op}: c\rightarrow x$, $s^{op}:c\rightarrow y$, $t^{op}:x\rightarrow y$.  Importantly, $c$ is still the domain of these arrows (and presumably for these arrows to exist, there must have been arrows $r,s,t$ in $\mathcal{C}$ such that $r:x\rightarrow c$, $s:y\rightarrow c$, and $t:y\rightarrow x$.

In $c/\mathcal{C}^{op}$, a morphism is $t^{op}(r^{op})=s^{op}$, and the objects here are $(r^{op}:c\rightarrow x)$ and $(s^{op}:c\rightarrow y)$.  So, when you pass to the opposite cateogry $(c/\mathcal{C}^{op})^{op}$, can you "reach in" to the objects and change *their* arrow directions (i.e., mutate the objects so that ($r^{op}:c\rightarrow x$) becomes ($r:x\rightarrow c)$)?  That's the only way I can get this framework to logically work.

Comment: You start out wrong: You're supposed to compare $\mathcal{C} / c$ and $(c / \mathcal{C}^{\mathrm{op}})^{\mathrm{op}}$, **not** $c / \mathcal{C}$ and $(c / \mathcal{C}^{\mathrm{op}})^{\mathrm{op}}$. If you do this your problem evaporates :)

Comment: I understand that I'm supposed to get to something like $\mathcal{C}/c$, but I'm starting with $\mathcal{C}^{op}$, then going to $c/\mathcal{C}^{op}$, then going to $(c/\mathcal{C}^{op})^{op}$, hoping to arrive at $\mathcal{C}/c$.  So my question is, once you're in $(c/\mathcal{C}^{op})$, and you want to "op" that, do you *also* reverse the arrows that define the objects?

Comment: No. By definition, ${{-}}^{\mathrm{op}}$ only reverses the arrows in the category, but the arrows that define the objects are, well, part of the objects, and therefore get left alone.

Comment: Got it.  That's what I thought.  But here's were I'm stuck.  I'm in $c/\mathcal{C}^{op}$, so my objects are $(r^{op}:c\rightarrow x$).  In $\mathcal{C}/c$, the arrows that are part of the object definition "point at" $c$ (i.e. have codomain of $c$).  I can't figure out how to reverse the arrows in $c/\mathcal{C}^{op}$ so that the objects point at $c$.

Comment: Ah, I think now I've understood where your confusion is coming from. The _outer_ ${{-}}^\mathrm{op}$ in $(c / \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op})^\mathrm{op}$ leaves objects unchanged. But comparing $c / \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$ to $\mathcal{C} / c$, there is no issue in going from the objects of one to those of the other, via $r^\mathrm{op} \mapsto r$ and vice-versa. I don't think the whole "mutating", "reaching in", etc. pseudo-terminology does you any favors here, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's drop the informal terminology of "reaching in", "mutating", "changing arrow directions" and so on and treat this exercise somewhat more formally; this will hopefully clear up the confusion. Namely, let's construct an isomorphism (that is, an invertible functor) $F\colon (c / \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op})^\mathrm{op} \to \mathcal{C} / c$.

What are the objects of $(c / \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op})^\mathrm{op}$? They're the same as the objects of $c / \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$, i.e. morphisms of the form $r^\mathrm{op}\colon c \to x$ where $r\colon x \to c$ is a morphism. This gives us an obvious choice for what $F$ should be on objects: we'll define $F(r^\mathrm{op}) = r$, which by definition is an object of $\mathcal{C} / c$.

As for morphisms, what's a morphism in $(c / \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op})^\mathrm{op}$? Well, it's the ${{-}}^\mathrm{op}$ of a morphism in $(c / \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op})$, and a morphism in $(c / \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op})$ from $r^\mathrm{op}\colon c \to x$ to $l^\mathrm{op}\colon c \to y$ is a morphism $h^\mathrm{op}\colon x \to y$ in $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$ such that $l^\mathrm{op} = h^\mathrm{op} \circ r^\mathrm{op}$, so you could write it as $(h^\mathrm{op})^\mathrm{op}\colon y \to x$. Again it should not come as a surprise that $F$ will be defined on morphisms as $F((h^\mathrm{op})^\mathrm{op}) = h$.

Of course one now needs to check that this actually defines a functor and find an inverse; this I leave as exercise :)

Comment: Thank you! Functors and categorical isomorphisms weren’t covered yet. :-)

Comment: @RicLouRiv Quite strange, given that you can't really make sense of the expression $\mathcal{C} / c \cong (c / \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op})^\mathrm{op}$ without knowing what an isomorphism of categories (and therefore a functor) is. I guess you can understand it informally... Either way, I guess you can parse functor/isomorphism here as "one-to-one assignment on objects and morphisms that preserves the structure (compositions of morphisms, identity morphisms, ...)" and make sense of it that way. Or learn about functors since that's coming up anyways :)